# Using an int variable for list placements

Tags: java, list

I'm not sure if my wording is correct. I'm hoping it'll be more clear with this.

```
Integer[] Performed = new Integer[3];  

public String dived(){        
        while (this.numberAttempts<3){
            int n = this.numberAttempts;
            int k = Dive.chosenRandomly();
            this.Performed[n] = k ;
            numberAttempts += 1;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I want the values of k(the random number) to be kept in a list so I know which numbers were chosen.
Is there a way for me to add values into the list in a while loop?

It works if I replace the n in [] with an integer<3.

Comment: Instead of an array of `Interger`, you'll have to use an  `ArrayList<Integer>`

Comment: What does it do otherwise?  Crash?  Or does it just give the wrong output?

Comment: `n` here cannot be `>=3` so I don't understand how replacing `n` can affect anything, unless `this.numberAttempts` can be negative

Comment: I'm required to use an array of Integer because that's the only method of arrays that I know of that can have a limit.

Comment: numberAttempts is originally 0. There are only 3 attempts allowed. So the while loop runs, after each loop, numberAttempts increases by 1.  A random number is generated in each loop. I want each random number to be recorded in the list.

Comment: Honestly, a for loop is much more suited for what you're trying to do.  It's syntactically much simpler since the use and incrementation if an index is build in.

Comment: figured it out. had a mistake with a related class. there was nothign wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use some list for example ArrayList and add random Integer to it.

```
List<Integer> Performed = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public String dived(){        
    while (this.numberAttempts<3){
        int n = this.numberAttempts;
        int k = Dive.chosenRandomly();
        this.Performed.add(k) ;
        numberAttempts += 1;
    }
    return null;
}
```